# Angular 5 JSONP request with HttpHeaders

Tags: angular, jsonp

I'm trying to perform a JSONP request with some HTTP header parameters. With **http.get** is simple:

```
let header = new HttpHeaders();
header.append(<header_param_name>, <header_param_value>);

this.http.get(<my_url>, { headers: header})
```

but when I try to do the same thing with **jsonp**...

```
this.http.jsonp(<my_url>, <callback_param>)
```

**where is the "options" parameter???** O_o
How can I send parameters in request header in a JSONP request?

Thanks for the response

Comment: Hi, maybe you can have a look at the documentation of angular for jsonp: https://angular.io/api/http/Jsonp. The RequestOptions contain the Headers

Comment: This class is deprecated in angular 5

Comment: check https://angular.io/api/http/Jsonp#deprecation-notes

Comment: If you follow the deprecation notes you get to my question. I try to use the @angular/common/http but in this class there isn't an "option" parameter!

Answer (score 0):

The **[official documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#jsonp)** says

> A suitable interceptor must be installed (e.g. via the HttpClientJsonpModule). If no such interceptor is reached, then the JSONP request will likely be rejected by the configured backend.

Comment: HttpClientJsonpModule is correctly installed and all jsonp request are performed correctly. My question is different! I want to send a parameter in HTTP header in a JSONP request..

Comment: Do you know what an http interceptor is ?

Comment: HTTP Interceptor it's not the right answer to my question. I want to send some parameter when I make the call `this.http.jsonp(<my_url>, <callback_param>) ` and not when an Interceptor "intercept" my request (and in these way all the http requests) because the interceptor can't have the parameters those I want to send in a particular http.jsonp call.

Comment: I thought you would understand but apparently not. If you want to set headers to your request, and the `jsonp` function doesn't allow you to do that, then you should use an interceptor to intercept the request and add the headers yourself. It won't do it on every request if you filter to only apply to this request (filter on method, url, payload, anything that is different from other requests).

Comment: I'm searching for an answer not for a bad workaround.

Comment: Then keep whining and denying help, and good luck with that issue of yours :)

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems there is not answer but only bad workarounds possible by design.

Comment: Wow, I'm flabbergasted.